# How to underline text in a plot title or label?

Tags: r, ggplot2, underline, plotmath

I can't seem to figure out how to underline any part of a plot title.

The best I could find was
[annotate("segment") done by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525964/underline-ggplot2-facet-titles%20#%20uses%20annotate()%20with%20geom_segment), and I have created a toy plot to illustrate its method.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

rngx <- 0.5 * range(df$x)[2]  # store mid-point of plot based on x-axis value
rngy <- 0.5 * range(df$y)[2]  # stores mid-point of y-axis for use in ggplot

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Oh how I wish for ..." ) +
  ggplot2::annotate("text", x = rngx, y = max(df$y) + 1, label = "underlining!", color = "red") +
  # create underline:
  ggplot2::annotate("segment", x = rngx-0.8, xend = rngx + 0.8, y= 10.1, yend=10.1)
```

[image]

[uses bquote(underline() with base R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VueDy.png)

[pertains to lines over and under nodes on a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124264/keeping-underline-length-of-a-label-in-r-consistent-with-label-length%20#%20node%20names%20with%20over%20and%20underline)

[uses plotmath and offers a workaround, but it didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988052/underline-text-in-a-barplot-in-r)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle(expression(paste("Oh how I wish for ", underline(underlining))))
```

Alternatively, as BondedDust points out in the comments, you can avoid the `paste()` call entirely, but watch out for the `for`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle(expression(Oh~how~I~wish~'for'~underline(underlining)))
```

Or another, even shorter approach suggested by baptiste that doesn't use `expression`, `paste()`, or the many tildes:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle(~"Oh how I wish for "*underline(underlining))
```

Comment: If using `expression` then why not `expression(Oh~how~I~wish~for ~underline(underlining))`. No need for the often confusing plotmath `paste()` call.

Comment: @BondedDust I didn't know about that approach.  When I try it, I get an error:  `Error: unexpected '~' in: 
"ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + 
  ggtitle(expression(Oh~how~I~wish~for ~"`  Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Oh damn. It's the f-word that's doing it. The R parser sees "for" and goes off looking 'for' (as it were) an index. Stupid machine!  Try: `expression(Oh~how~I~wish~'for'~underline(underlining))`. It makes the same parse error with `in`.

Comment: `ggtitle(~"Oh how I wish for "*underline(underlining))` is probably easiest

Comment: Excellent!  I have accepted the answer (and appreciate all the comments).  Would you mind explaining the use of the tilde ~ and the asterisk *?  Thank you.

Comment: @lawyeR They are plotmath separators.  The tilde is a space separator/connector and the asterisk is a non-space separator/connector.  They can work well for connecting expressions and text in a readable way.  For more info/documentation, you'll have to ask someone like baptiste (by using @baptiste), who is a real plotting guru.  I actually don't know where the relevant documentation is.