# Underlining specific elements of scale_x_continous labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm aware there are [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470293/how-to-underline-text-in-a-plot-title-or-label-ggplot2) on the same issue, but I couldn't use any to solve my specific problem.

I have this structured added to a ggplot object:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2.25, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.75, 7.75, 8.75, 10, 11.25, 12.25, 13.35),
                     labels = rev(c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
                                    "E", "F", "G", "H",
                                    "I", "J", "K", "L")))
```

Moreover, I add this to set some elements to bold and change sizes (nevermind the different axis, there's a `coord_flip()` added to the ggplot structure as well).

```
 axis.text.y = element_text(face=c("plain", "plain", "plain", "bold", "plain", "plain", "bold", "plain", "plain", "plain", "bold", "plain"), 
                                        size=c(7.75, 7.75, 7.75, 9, 7.75, 7.75, 9, 7.75, 7.75, 7.75, 9, 7.75),
                                        hjust=0),
```

I'd also like for every bolded element to be underlined; I tried using the `geom_label_repel` but it kept running into a `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace text, `"text"` with `expression(~underline("text"))` to underline. You might also want to add `~bold` to get `expression(~bold(~underline("text")))`. In your case changing the scale line to:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2.25, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.75, 7.75, 8.75, 10, 11.25, 12.25, 13.35),
                     labels = rev(c("A", expression(~underline("B")), "C", "D", 
                                    "E", expression(~bold(~underline("F"))), "G", "H",
                                    expression(~bold(~underline("I"))), "J", "K", "L")))
```

should do the trick.