# How to use bold, italic and underline in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I use bold, italic and underline in a graphic title or axis in ggplot2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to underline text in a plot title or label? (ggplot2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470293/how-to-underline-text-in-a-plot-title-or-label-ggplot2)

Comment: @SinhNguyen it isn't enough because I want bolda and italic.

Comment: You may be interested in package **ggtext**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trial with the links I shared in comment - Not sure what you want to achieve though

```r
data <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data, mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  ggtitle(expression(atop(paste(bold("Bold "), italic(" italic"),
    underline(" underline"), 
    underline(bold(" underline can go with bold")), 
    underline(italic(" or italic"))),
    paste(bolditalic(" - and italic & bold together"),
    underline(bolditalic(" - and all together"))))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>