# put the global variable(here is 'var') in the bolditalic string in ggtitle of ggplot using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, global-variables, bold

reference : [How to use bold, italic and underline in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504377/how-to-use-bold-italic-and-underline-in-ggplot2)

Hi, I want to ***put the global variable(here is 'var') in the bolditalic string*** in ggtitle of ggplot using for loop.

The graph doesn't have a value corresponding to 'var', it just comes out as 'var'.

```
a <- data.frame(date = 1:5, co2 = 11:15, year = 2021:2025) 
var = 2021
for (var in 2021:2025) {
    print(
        a %>% 
            filter(year == var) %>% 
            ggplot(aes(date, co2)) +
            geom_point() +
            ggtitle(expression(paste(
                bolditalic(var),
                bolditalic("KOR CO2"))))
    )
}
```

I want graph titles to be ***2021 KOR CO2***, ***2022 KOR CO2***, ..., ***2025 KOR CO2***.

Can you please solve this problem?

Comment: Try `ggtitle(bquote(bolditalic(.(as.character(var))~"KOR CO2")))`

Comment: @MrFlick OMG!! It's working!!! I LUV YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to MrFlick's solution: `ggplot` offers automated subsetting and plotting data by one or two grouping variables. You can achieve such *facetted* plots conveniently with `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid`.
In your case:

```
a %>%
    ggplot(aes(date, co2)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ year)
```

Comment: Thanks very much !!! It's really useful. I didn't think about it at all. Thanks again!!!